# Save a figure in a particular pixel size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to save a picture that is 128x128 pixels. I used `bbox_inches='tight'` but that doesn't work. Is there a way to save the figure in the specified pixels?

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def save_image(cnt,noise):      
    generated_images = generator.predict(noise)

    generated_images = 0.5 * generated_images + 0.5
    
    im = plt.imshow(generated_images[0, :, :, 0], cmap='Greys_r')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig("/content/drive/MyDrive/MultiDiscriminator/single/epoch" + str(cnt+1) + ".png")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Try setting `bbox_inches=0, pad_inches=0` in `savefig`.

Comment: that didn't work, the images was bigger than when using bbox_inches='tight'

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by combining the [`figsize` and `dpi` properties](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html?highlight=figure.figsize#the-default-matplotlibrc-file) of `matplotlib`. `figsize` describes how large the image will be, and `dpi` describes how many pixels there are per inch. So the number of pixels will be `figsize`*`dpi`.
E.g. for a 128x128 images that is 1 inch x 1 inch we can set `figsize = ( 1, 1 )` and `dpi = 128`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace( 0, 1 )
y = np.square( x )

# set params via config
mpl.rcParams[ 'figure.figsize' ] = ( 1, 1 )
mpl.rcParams[ 'figure.dpi' ] = 128

img = plt.plot( x, y )
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.tight_layout()

plt.savefig( 'dpi.png' )

# set params with figure and `savefig`
fig.set_size_inches( 1, 1 )
plt.savefig( 'dpi-2.png', dpi = 128 )
```